# Warning while adding primary output to the setup project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, installation

I'm trying to create setup for my project. I added the new project with "Setup . When I add primary output to the project, I got the following warning.

> "The following files may have dependencies that cannot be determined automatically. Please confirm that all dependencies have been added to the project C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\OPJL9CEH.K72\TOHQTNEM.N1Q\weba..tion_5eaf22060995d42c_0001.0000_b98a6abda035b9be\LeadTools\Ltocxu.ocx C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\OPJL9CEH.K72\TOHQTNEM.N1Q\weba..tion_5eaf22060995d42c_0001.0000_b98a6abda035b9be\LeadTools\LtocxVariantu.dll

Please guide me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This warning is a "general" warning and not one that may necessarily stop the software from working. It only means that since OCX and DLL files are older technology, the new setup project may not be able to detect the dependencies for these files. You may want to check the LeadTools documentation or find the dependencies manually and add them to the distribution as required.

Again, since this is a general warning for the tool (setup project) itself and not your project specifically, even if you add any missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the warning might be valid. The old LEAD Main OCX (Ltocxu.ocx) did require additional DLLs to work. Some of them are directly linked as dependencies like the kernel and display DLLs (LtKrnu.dll and Ltdisu.dll).

Others are dynamically loaded if needed, such as file format DLLs.

You should be able to find full details in the topic "Files to be Included with Your Application" in LEADTOOLS help files for your specific version of the toolkit.